# slidetoggle single previous element (with multiple instance)

Tags: jquery, selector, slidetoggle

i have a dead simple question as i'm a total beginner to jquery.
i'd simply like to select **one** instance of a previous element (which has multiple instances) and toggle it's visibility (via slidetoggle).

html (edit):

```
    <div class="infobox">some info that appears if the following/div is clicked</div>
    <div class="buttonset">
    <div class="button">show info</div>
    </div>

    <div class="infobox">some other info that appears if the following/div is clicked</div>
    <div class="buttonset">
    <div class="button">show info</div>
    </div>
```

jquery (does not work):

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".infobox").slideToggle(250);
});
```

i'm aware that "infobox" is not really a parent of the button class but i have no clue which selector to use. would be gracious for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use .prev()

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
    $(this).parent().prev(".infobox").slideToggle(250);
});
```

Comment: thanks so much, but this didn't work — i suppose i provided false exemplary html.. the "button" is actually inside another div — i corrected the html.

Comment: Yeah that makes a difference ;) Updated - try it now... This code assumes that the html looks like in your example.